# Zend Gdata Spreadsheet insertRow throwing HttpException

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata, gdata-api

I am trying to insert a row in a worksheet using `Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets` with the following code:

```
$gdClient->insertRow(array('a'=>'gggggg','b'=>'hhhhh'), $currKey, $currWkshtId);
```

Both `$currKey` and `$currWkshtId` are correct, but it returns this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with
>   message 'Expected response code 200, got 400.  We're sorry, a server
>   error occurred. Please wait a bit and try reloading your spreadsheet.'

Does anyone know what the cause of this error is and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because I need to put header name in a worksheet columns.

Anyone know if they have any name by default? or is possible referenciate the column in another way?

Comment: Also worth mentioning that you should use lowercase letters in the array keys even if you have capitalized the strings in the first row. I had "Name", "Address" in the first row, but got the HttpException and only disappeared when I changed the array keys from "Name" to "name" and "Address" to "address". I hope this helps someone.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, that was definitely helpful! Using lowercase solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google assumes that the first row in the spreadsheet is the header row, so the text in the first row becomes the header name for the column. In objective-c you must also remove spaces and convert the string to lower-case when referencing the column name, so that's probably true for php too. Try converting $currKey to lower case and removing spaces before sending it in.

Comment: this is an example of why sometimes I criticise google heavily, they should be full of the smartest programmers on the planet, yet some of their decisions are so bone-headedly stupid, it's hard to understand how they walk without tripping up....who in their right mind "assumes" the first row is a header row...